# Change to Username instead of Email Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having some issues with changing Email to Username.

The `protected $username = 'username';` Doesn't seem to work for me.

Where can I change the DB Register Query and DB Login Query?

Comment: Can you post your login view?

Comment: This was fixed awhile ago.

Comment: glad to hear that. adding protected username in AuthController should do that job for you. You was correct. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to login by username instead of email use this

```
$credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');
```

instead of

```
$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
```

to check credential here `attempt($credentials)`

in `AuthenticateController.php`

Comment: What about registering? I get a DB error cause it's trying to find name, not username.

Comment: you need username there, or change it to name

Comment: Where is AuthenticateController.php

Comment: app/Http/Controllers

Comment: Actually wait no. My username isn't being detected. Whenever I register a new account with a username, it doesn't get inserted into the db. Same with logging in, doesn't want to check my username.